# Visual Studio 2010 - How to enable prompt to delete file from disk when removed from project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2005, when you remove a file from a C++ project (by right-clicking in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Remove"), it asks you whether you just want to delete the reference, or also delete the file itself from disk.

In Visual Studio 2010, this prompt seems to have disappeared (or I have accidentally turned it off). This means that every time I delete a file in the Solution Explorer, I have to immediately hunt it down and delete it with Windows Explorer (otherwise I'll forget and it will stay around forever). How do I get the prompt back?

I found some documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebzhwsk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explaining the difference between "Remove" and "Delete", and that "Delete" doesn't exist for C++ projects (but no reason is given). Maybe it's really just not possible? If so, what an annoying regression.

Comment: If the documentation clearly says it doesn't exist for C++ projects, what exactly is your question? If you're asking why they made that decision, no one here knows. This reads more like a complaint than an actual question.

Comment: huh, when I press the Del key, or right click a file and select "Remove" in a VC++ project, I'm prompted if I want to Remove or Delete the file...

Comment: @Ken White: Even from reading that documentation, I'm not sure if the entire ability is missing, or if you just can't get to it that way. In VS2005, there was no "Delete" option either, but the functionality was still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the remove or delete file dialog only if the selected file is stored in the project folder. If the file is stored outside of the project folder the file reference is removed without dialog.

This behaviour is still the same for e.g. VS2013. I created a user voice request to change this behaviour here. IMHO your file hierarchy should not make any difference.

You can vote for the change here:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9146353-remove-delete-dialog-should-show-up-when-deleting

Comment: Hmmm. Is the project folder the folder containing the project file? Yeah none of my source files are in there (the code is cross-platform; I have multiple different project files in a separate directory). Voted!

Comment: @Karu We created an Visual Studio extension to fix this weird behaviour. You can download it [here](https://gallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ebc2b8d7-9f1b-4e9d-88f7-daf924e422ec).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one is using Sourcegear Vault as the source control system, you can enable the prompt by going to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Integration Options -> and check on "Show warning before deleting items from source control"